# How to write SQL Query to join two tables with mappings table and get formatted output with only one row per result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.

---

```
Table: "Foods"
-----------
ID    Name
-----------
1     Apple
2     Strawberry
3     Celery
4     Peanuts
5     Toffee
```

---

```
Table: "Tags"
------------
ID     Name
------------
A      Sweet
B      Fruit
C      Crunchy
```

---

```
Table: "Mappings"
-------------------------
ID    TagID     FoodID
-------------------------
101   A          1
102   A          2
103   A          5
104   B          2   
105   C          1
106   C          3
107   C          4
108   C          5
```

I'm trying to run a query and get results that are formatted like this:

```
** DESIRED RESULTS OUTPUT FORMAT **
------------------------------------------------------
ID    Name          IsSweet     IsFruit     IsCrunchy
------------------------------------------------------
1     Apple               1           1             1
2     Strawberry          1           1             0
3     Celery              0           0             1
4     Peanuts             0           0             1
5     Toffee              1           0             1
```

Here is the query I'm currently using **that is not working** how I would like:

```
SELECT foods.id, foods.name, 
  IF(tags.name = "Sweet", 1, 0) IsSweet, 
  IF(tags.name = "Fruit", 1, 0) IsFruit,
  IF(tags.name="Crunchy", 1, 0) IsCrunchy,
  from Foods, Tags, Mappings 
    where Foods.ID = Mappings.FoodID and Mappings.TagID = Tags.ID
```

I'm getting results like the following, where every food item is repeated N times, once for each tag that exists.

```
** ACTUAL RESULTS I'M GETTING **
------------------------------------------------------
ID    Name          IsSweet     IsFruit     IsCrunchy
------------------------------------------------------
1     Apple               1           0             0
1     Apple               0           1             0
1     Apple               0           0             1
2     Strawberry          1           0             0
2     Strawberry          0           1             0
3     Celery              0           0             1
4     Peanuts             0           0             1
5     Toffee              1           0             0
5     Toffee              0           0             1
```

How can I write my query to get the results formatted how I would like? I've tried Outer Joins, and tried to use `CASE/WHEN` statements or  `GROUP BY` but I haven't figured it out yet.

Can anyone offer some direction for me please?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Apply max:

```
   SELECT foods.id, foods.name, 
        max(IF(tags.name = "Sweet", 1, 0)) IsSweet, 
        max(IF(tags.name = "Fruit", 1, 0)) IsFruit,
        max(IF(tags.name="Crunchy", 1, 0)) IsCrunchy
   from Foods, Tags, Mappings 
   where Foods.ID = Mappings.FoodID and Mappings.TagID = Tags.ID
   group by foods.id, foods.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use commas to separate list of tables. Always use `JOINS` like:

```
SELECT foods.id, foods.name, 
  MAX(IF(tags.name = "Sweet", 1, 0)) IsSweet, 
  MAX(IF(tags.name = "Fruit", 1, 0)) IsFruit,
  MAX(IF(tags.name="Crunchy", 1, 0)) IsCrunchy,
  from Foods
  left join Mappings on Foods.ID = Mappings.FoodID 
  left join Tags on Mappings.TagID = Tags.ID
  group by foods.id
```

This makes it really clear and efficient how the tables are related. Other the result is a cartesian product and the `where` just filters its output (which is the wrong result).

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Edit: left joins as per dissussion

Comment: Compared to @dandarc's answer (that I copied the MAX bits off), I've only grouped by `food.id` as its a unique identifier so there's no need to group by anything else in the food table.

Comment: I work primarily in Oracle, which often gives me an error if I don't include everything in the group by that isn't in an aggregate function. So I tend to just do that by default. 

While I prefer the 'join' syntax as well for clarity, I disagree that "cartesean product and filters" gives the wrong result - for inner joins, such as we have here, those are logically equivalent. Many databases will come up with the same execution plan either way.

Comment: Thanks - that works! But I've got one more question now. If I have a `Foods` row that doesn't have any corresponding `Tags`, how can I get that food to show in the output results as well?

Comment: instead of inner joins, do left outer joins. There is a good graphic at w3Schools for the basic joins - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thanks - that's perfect. I tried a left outer join first and then I was thinking I needed a right outer join second, but two left outer joins is exactly what's needed. Very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Second, you can simplify your logic by using the fact that MySQL treats boolean values as integers.

Third, you need `GROUP BY`:

And finally, the standard delimiter for strings in SQL is the single quote.  Although MySQL supports double quotes as well, you should get used to using single quotes.

So:

```
select f.id, f.name, 
       max(t.name = 'Sweet') as IsSweet, 
       max(t.name = 'Fruit') as IsFruit,
       max(t.name = 'Crunchy') as IsCrunchy
from Foods f join
     Mappings m
     on f.ID = m.FoodID join
     Tags t
     on t.ID = m.TagID
group by f.id, f.name
```